# LangChain Agent that uses a tool multiple times until a stopping criteria is met

Tags: agent, langchain, large-language-model

I want to create an agent with LangChain and followed one of their tutorials.

In my use case, I want to generate text with gpt and score the generated text with some kind of metrics. If the score of these metrics is too low, I want the agent to generate new text with the feedback of my metrics.

Right now, the agent generates the text and scores it using the metrics I provide as tools.
Each tool is used only once and not recursively.

The agent looks like this:

```
agent = LLMSingleActionAgent(
    llm_chain=llm_chain,
    output_parser=output_parser,
    stop=["\nObservation:"],
    allowed_tools=tool_names,
    max_iterations_per_tool=10,
)
```

In the agent template I described that the agent should regenerate the text when tool x returns a value below a certain threshold, but this does not work.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?